# Как передать данные из формы на другую страницу с помощью action?

Tags: javascript

Мой html:

```
  <form action="result.html" method="GET">
    <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10">

    </textarea>

    <button id="split">Разбить на слова</button>
  </form>
```

Мой js:

```
document.getElementById('split').addEventListener("click", function () {
  var result = document.getElementById('text').value.match(/[a-zа-яё]+/gi);

  // document.createTextNode(result);

  let resultBlock = document.createElement('resultBlock');
  // div.className = "alert";
  resultBlock.innerHTML = result;

  // document.body.append(resultBlock);
});

document.getElementById('result').value = window.location.search;
```

Я хочу текст из textarea передать в переменную и затем записать значение этой переменной в блок по id на другой странице. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Через кукис, или localstorage.

Comment: Мне нужна реализация способа через метод get или post

Comment: так так и надо написать в вопросе, что передача через сервер. result.html меняешь на result.php, в result.php в нужном месте пишешь  <?php echo $_GET['text'] ; ?>

Comment: Спасибо большое!